# mssql subquery aggregate - sum wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to get some data in tsql (MSSQL2014) where I use a subquery to get a sum of some foreign key'd data table.

The structure looks like this:

```
TABLE [AggregateData](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Aggregate_UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DataDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SizeAvailable] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SizeTotal] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SizeUsed] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PercentageUsed] [int] NOT NULL
)

TABLE [Aggregate](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Cluster_UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DiskTypeID] [int] NOT NULL
)

TABLE [DiskType](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TypeName] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)

TABLE [Volume](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Aggregate_UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ServiceClassID] [int] NULL,
    [ProtocolID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EnvironmentID] [int] NOT NULL
)

TABLE [VolumeData](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Volume_UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DataDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SizeAvailable] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SizeTotal] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SizeUsed] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PercentageUsed] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Now in the end I need to get the following data:

**DataDate, DiskType, AggregateSizes (Avail, Used, Total), Aggregated Volume Sizes (Sum of Avail, Used, Total of Volumes in that Aggregate)**

I was thinking of using subqueries but when trying to get the values for a specific Aggregate only (for testing, easier for my to check) I get wrong values in the subquery.

Here is what I tried;

```
SELECT
  AggregateData.DataDate,
  AggregateData.SizeTotal AS AggregateSizeTotal,
  (SELECT
    SUM(VolumeData.SizeTotal)
  FROM VolumeData
  LEFT JOIN Volume
    ON VolumeData.Volume_UUID = Volume.UUID
  WHERE Aggregate_UUID = Volume.Aggregate_UUID
  AND VolumeData.DataDate = AggregateData.DataDate)
  VolumeSizeTotal

FROM AggregateData

WHERE AggregateData.Aggregate_UUID = 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C'
ORDER BY AggregateData.DataDate
```

But this seems me to not get the correct value for the subquery sum. My subquery sum is way to high so I assume my where clause is incorrect (or the whole setup ;) ...)

- **So, question 1. Are subqueries the way to go or should I do it differently?**
- **If (question 1 == true) Whats wrong with my subquery?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify *all* column names.  I would recommend using table abbreviations.  The problem is `Aggregate_UUID = v.Aggregate_UUID`.  The first column is coming from `v` so this is (essentially) a no-op.

Presumably, you want this correlated with the outer query:

```
SELECT ad.DataDate, ad.SizeTotal AS AggregateSizeTotal,
       (SELECT SUM(vd.SizeTotal)
        FROM VolumeData vd LEFT JOIN
             Volume v
             ON vd.Volume_UUID = v.UUID
        WHERE ad.Aggregate_UUID = v.Aggregate_UUID AND
              ad.DataDate = vd.DataDate
       ) VolumeSizeTotal
FROM AggregateData ad
WHERE ad.Aggregate_UUID = 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C'
ORDER BY ad.DataDate
```

Comment: Yes you are right. This looks good with the subquery in the select. Now for all other columns I need I would need to add another subquery in the select because as far as I know it can only return 1 value when used in the select. That would make it a bit cumbersome to use. So while valid I thing my initial approach with using the subquery in the select is not ideal. I'll try it with the subquery in the join. Seems the better approach for my need.

Comment: @Marc . . . If you have *another* question that involves multiple columns, then you should ask it as a question rather than in a comment.

Comment: You're right. So I'll ask another question with the second part. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JOIN instead of correlated subquery (O(n^2) performance) -

```
SELECT
  t1.DataDate,
  t1.SizeTotal AS AggregateSizeTotal,
  t2.total VolumeSizeTotal
FROM AggregateData t1 left join (SELECT
    DataDate, SUM(VolumeData.SizeTotal) total
  FROM VolumeData
  LEFT JOIN Volume
    ON VolumeData.Volume_UUID = Volume.UUID
  WHERE Aggregate_UUID = Volume.Aggregate_UUID
  group by DataDate) t2 on t1.datadate = t2.dataDate
WHERE t1.Aggregate_UUID = 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C';
```

Answer (score 0):

Going for a query to return the desired end results, I would use something like this:

> Now in the end I need to get the following data: **DataDate, DiskType, AggregateSizes (Avail, Used, Total), Aggregated Volume Sizes (Sum of Avail, Used, Total of Volumes in that Aggregate)**

```
select 
      AggregateUuid          = a.uuid
    , DiskType               = dt.TypeName
    , DataDate               = ad.DataDate
    , AggregateSizeAvailable = ad.SizeAvailable
    , AggregateSizeUsed      = ad.SizeUsed
    , AggregateSizeTotal     = ad.SizeTotal
    , VolumeSizeAvailable    = sum(vd.SizeAvailable)
    , VolumeSizeUsed         = sum(vd.SizeUsed)
    , VolumeSizeTotal        = sum(vd.SizeTotal)
  from [Aggregate] a
      inner join DiskType      dt  on dt.Id             = a.DiskTypeId
      inner join AggregateData ad  on ad.Aggregate_uuid = a.uuid
      left  join Volume         v  on  v.Aggregate_uuid = a.uuid 
      left  join VolumeData     vd on vd.Volume_uuid    = v.uuid
                                 and vd.DataDate       = ad.DataDate
  where a.uuid = 'C58D0098-D1A4-4ee9-A0E9-7de3eeb6275C'
  group by 
      a.uuid
    , dt.TypeName
    , ad.DataDate
    , ad.SizeAvailable
    , ad.SizeUsed
    , ad.SizeTotal
  order by a.uuid, ad.DataDate;
```

---

test setup: http://rextester.com/HZZHLI45077

```
create table DiskType(
    Id int identity(1,1) not null
  , TypeName nvarchar(255) null
);
set identity_insert DiskType on;
insert into DiskType (Id, TypeName) values 
  (1,'Type1'), (2,'Type2');
set identity_insert DiskType off;

create table [Aggregate](
    Id bigint identity(1,1) not null
  , uuid uniqueidentifier not null
  , Name nvarchar(255) not null
  , Cluster_uuid uniqueidentifier not null
  , DiskTypeid int not null 
);

insert into [Aggregate] (uuid, name, cluster_uuid, disktypeid) 
            select 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C', 'ex', newid(), 1;

create table AggregateData(
    Id bigint identity(1,1) not null
  , Aggregate_uuid uniqueidentifier not null
  , DataDate date not null
  , SizeAvailable bigint not null
  , SizeTotal bigint not null
  , SizeUsed bigint not null
  , PercentageUsed int not null
);

insert into AggregateData 
            select 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C', '20170101', 12,100,87,87
  union all select 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C', '20170102', 9,100,90,90
  union all select 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C', '20170103', 6,100,93,93;

create table Volume(
    Id bigint identity(1,1) not null
  , uuid uniqueidentifier not null
  , Name nvarchar(255) not null
  , Aggregate_uuid uniqueidentifier not null
  , ServiceClassid int null
  , Protocolid int not null
  , Environmentid int not null
);
insert into Volume 
            select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001', 'v1'
                , 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C', null, 1, 1
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002', 'v2'
                , 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C', null, 1, 1
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003', 'v3'
                , 'C58D0098-D1A4-4EE9-A0E9-7DE3EEB6275C', null, 1, 1;

create table VolumeData(
    Id bigint identity(1,1) not null
  , Volume_uuid uniqueidentifier not null
  , DataDate date not null
  , SizeAvailable bigint not null
  , SizeTotal bigint not null
  , SizeUsed bigint not null
  , PercentageUsed int not null
);

insert into VolumeData 
            select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001', '20170101', 4,33,29,88
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002', '20170101', 4,33,29,88
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003', '20170101', 4,34,29,87
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001', '20170102', 3,33,30,91
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002', '20170102', 3,33,30,91
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003', '20170102', 3,34,30,90
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001', '20170103', 2,33,31,94
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002', '20170103', 2,33,31,94
  union all select '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003', '20170103', 2,34,31,93

go
/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

select 
      AggregateUuid          = a.uuid
    , DiskType               = dt.TypeName
    , DataDate               = convert(varchar(10),ad.DataDate,121)
    , AggregateSizeAvailable = ad.SizeAvailable
    , AggregateSizeUsed      = ad.SizeUsed
    , AggregateSizeTotal     = ad.SizeTotal
    , VolumeSizeAvailable    = sum(vd.SizeAvailable)
    , VolumeSizeUsed         = sum(vd.SizeUsed)
    , VolumeSizeTotal        = sum(vd.SizeTotal)
  from [Aggregate] a
      inner join DiskType      dt  on dt.Id             = a.DiskTypeId
      inner join AggregateData ad  on ad.Aggregate_uuid = a.uuid
      left  join Volume         v  on  v.Aggregate_uuid = a.uuid 
      left  join VolumeData     vd on vd.Volume_uuid    = v.uuid
                                 and vd.DataDate       = ad.DataDate
  where a.uuid = 'C58D0098-D1A4-4ee9-A0E9-7de3eeb6275C'
  group by 
      a.uuid
    , dt.TypeName
    , ad.DataDate
    , ad.SizeAvailable
    , ad.SizeUsed
    , ad.SizeTotal
  order by a.uuid, ad.DataDate;
```

results in:

```
+--------------------------------------+----------+------------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+
|            AggregateUuid             | DiskType |  DataDate  | AggregateSizeAvailable | AggregateSizeUsed | AggregateSizeTotal | VolumeSizeAvailable | VolumeSizeUsed | VolumeSizeTotal |
+--------------------------------------+----------+------------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| c58d0098-d1a4-4ee9-a0e9-7de3eeb6275c | Type1    | 2017-01-01 |                     12 |                87 |                100 |                  12 |             87 |             100 |
| c58d0098-d1a4-4ee9-a0e9-7de3eeb6275c | Type1    | 2017-01-02 |                      9 |                90 |                100 |                   9 |             90 |             100 |
| c58d0098-d1a4-4ee9-a0e9-7de3eeb6275c | Type1    | 2017-01-03 |                      6 |                93 |                100 |                   6 |             93 |             100 |
+--------------------------------------+----------+------------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: That will give me one entry per volume but I would need 1 entry per aggregate with the volume size columns being the sum of all volumes in that particular aggregate. Sorry for not being clear in my initial post.

Comment: @Marc Updated answer removes volume name, this should return what you were looking for now.

Comment: This still gets me multiple rows with the same aggregate per volume as there is no group by 'volume'

Comment: Since we are summing all the volume data, you wouldn't want to group by volume. Is `Aggregate (uuid)` a unique column or is `Aggregate (uuid, disktype)` unique?
Is `AggregateData (uuid, datadate)` unique or are there rows for the same date with different values for `SizeAvailable, SizeUsed, or SizeTotal`?

Comment: Aggregate(uuid) is unique but also Aggreage(uuid, disktype). Each aggregate only has 1 disk type.
In the AggregateData there is one (and only one) row for each aggregae on each day. 
VolumeData has one row for each volume on each day.
Each Aggregate can have zero (unlikely but possible) to many volumes in it (Volume has AggregateUUID in it)

Comment: Updated answer with test data to your ddl and ran the query, output is as expected. Is this different from the results you are getting?